# Spring Boot Externalized Configuration with Jasypt encryption(Bootstrap issue)

Tags: spring-boot, jasypt

In my Spring boot application, when I try to connect to MongoDB using `uri` pattern with Jasypt encrypted password I’m getting Auth exception. While debugging I do see that the Jasypt decryption is not happening when using URI whereas with individual mongo configuration (see below) the connection is successful. In the log, the encrypted string `ENC(Qev1vJ3DummyPSUApeQfgdgfd==)` is getting printed as it is with no decryption. The whole configuration is passed via command-line using [SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config)

Using `uri`:(Not working)

*java -Dspring.application.json="{below json}" -jar myapp.jar*

```
{
    "spring": {
        "data": {
            "mongodb": {
                "uri": "mongodb://myusername:${spring.data.mongodb.password}@localhost:27017/mydb",
                "password": "${mongodb.password}"
            }
        }
    },
    "jasypt": {
        "encryptor": {
            "password": "myjasypt-password"
        }
    },
    "mongodb": {
        "password": "ENC(Qev1vJ3DummyPSUApeQfgdgfd==)"
    }
}
```

`With Individual property setting`: (Working fine)

*java -Dspring.application.json="{below json}" -jar myapp.jar*

```
{
    "spring": {
        "data": {
            "mongodb": {
                "host": "localhost",
                "port": "27017",
                "database": "mydb",
                "username": "myusername",
                "password": "${mongodb.password}"
            }
        }
    },
    "jasypt": {
        "encryptor": {
            "password": "myjasypt-password"
        }
    },
    "mongodb": {
        "password": "ENC(Qev1vJ3DummyPSUApeQfgdgfd==)"
    }
}
```

Spring Boot: 1.5.2.RELEASE | MongoDB:3.4.2 | Jasypt: 1.14

Exception:

```
com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=null, userName=myusername, source=mydb, password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties={}}
```

It appears that Jasypt decryption is not happening when it is being used in uri. I'm not sure whether this could be related to Bootstrapping of configuration. Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Don't know if you edited the URI example, but there are two commas before the `jasypt` property, meaning that example is malformed json

Comment: Corrected my typo in the question. Copy and pasted individually which caused the typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. It appears that this issue exists in Jasypt 1.14 and got fixed in version 1.17 and above.

If in case 1.14 version cannot be changed, add the below entry in *resources/META-INF/spring.factories*

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.JasyptSpringBootAutoConfiguration
```

In Version 1.17, Jasypt's `EnableEncryptablePropertiesConfiguration` uses [Applicationcontextinitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextInitializer.html) to customize the `Environment`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest specifying the encrypted property directly, like so

```
{
    "spring": {
        "data": {
            "mongodb": {
                "uri": "mongodb://myusername:${mongodb.password}@localhost:27017/mydb"
            }
        }
    },
    "jasypt": {
        "encryptor": {
            "password": "myjasypt-password"
        }
    },
    "mongodb": {
        "password": "ENC(Qev1vJ3DummyPSUApeQfgdgfd==)"
    }
}
```

In my book that would make the two examples equivalent